# Quickly Convert Text To Numbers or Dates Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to QUICKLY convert numbers/dates stored as text (without knowing exactly which cells are affected) to their correct type using VBA.

I get data in an ugly text-deliminated format, and I wrote a macro that basically does text-to-columns on it, but is more robust (regular text-to-columns will not work on my data, and I also don't want to waste time going through the wizard every time...).  But, since I have to use arrays to process the data efficiently, everything gets stored as a String (and is thus transferred to the worksheet as text).

I don't want to have to cycle through every cell, as this takes a LONG time (these are huge data files - I need to use arrays to process them).  Is there a simple command I can apply to the entire range to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some data and an example of your code?

Comment: I assume each column contains the same data type, so specifying a format for each column as to the data type and applying it to the whole worksheet may work... So long as this is done BEFORE the data is inserted.  For example text with a leading 0 listed as general will have the 0 dropped, whereas if the column is specified as text, will not.  The same concept holds true for dates and other data types.

Comment: Will post in a minute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the data type of the columns  modify the column from general to the correct data type and the placement of text data should get automatically converted... here's an example where I pasted the text 012345 into different columns having different data types.  Note how the displayed value is different for the different types but the value is retained (except on number and general which truncate a leading 0.

However if you don't know what field is of what type... you're really out of luck.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I have no way of knowing which column will contain which data type, it always changes.

Comment: Then the answer yo your question is no.  If you don't know the data type being processed then I know of no good way to figure this out. Quickly or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way is there. Just multiply 1 with the data in the column have text to converted as number, whether it is text or not it will convert to numbers only.

Read the following the link for more.

http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/09/02/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-tip/